# PNaCl build failure (ERROR-missing-arm-trusted-toolchain: not found)

Tags: llvm, google-nativeclient

I tried to build PNaCl on Ubuntu 14.04 (chroot to 12.04 led to the same result). I ran 'pnacl/build.sh all' and build failed on "LIBGCC_EH (from GCC 4.6)" step

```
[22:55] MISC-TOOLS           Building sel_ldr (arm)


 *********************************************************************
 | 
 | ERROR
 | 
 *********************************************************************
COMMAND: ./scons MODE=opt-host platform=arm naclsdk_validate=0 sysinfo=0 -j8 sel_ldr

LOGFILE: /home/dmitry/chromium-35.0.1916.114/src/native_client/pnacl/build/log/arm_sel_ldr

PWD: /home/dmitry/chromium-35.0.1916.114/src/native_client
```

LOGFILE containes the following:

```
======================================================================
B U I L D - O U T P U T:
======================================================================
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
________Compiling scons-out/opt-linux-arm/obj/src/trusted/service_runtime/li    nux/nacl_bootstrap_munge_phdr.o
________Compiling scons-out/opt-linux-arm/obj/src/trusted/service_runtime/li    nux/nacl_bootstrap.o
sh: 1: ERROR-missing-arm-trusted-toolchain: not found
________Compiling scons-out/opt-linux-arm/obj/src/trusted/service_runtime/na    cl_test_injection_main.o
sh: 1: ERROR-missing-arm-trusted-toolchain: not found
________Compiling scons-out/opt-linux-arm/obj/src/trusted/service_runtime/se    l_main.o
sh: 1: ERROR-missing-arm-trusted-toolchain: not found
________Compiling scons-out/opt-linux-arm/obj/src/trusted/debug_stub/abi.o
sh: 1: ERROR-missing-arm-trusted-toolchain: not found
________Compiling scons-out/opt-linux-arm/obj/src/trusted/debug_stub/debug_s    tub.o
sh: 1: ERROR-missing-arm-trusted-toolchain: not found
________Compiling scons-out/opt-linux-arm/obj/src/trusted/debug_stub/nacl_de    bug.o
```

Could you explain me how to fix the failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of answers:
Firstly, you should no longer use `pnacl/build.sh` to build the PNaCl toolchain: instead use `toolchain_build/toolchain_build_pnacl.py`. The documentation about how to build the PNaCl toolchain can be found [here](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/pnacl/developing-pnacl) and has been updated to reflect the new script.

Secondly, the actual problem you are describing comes not from building the toolchain, but from building `sel_ldr`, which is the command-line standalone NaCl trusted runtime (i.e. ELF loader, validator, service runtime, etc). The build.sh script builds `sel_ldr` for ARM to use for testing the toolchain, which uses an emulator for ARM. The trusted runtime is built using the ARM cross-compiler packages that come with Ubuntu. A script that will install these packages for you on 12.04 can be found in the NaCl repo in `tools/trusted_cross_toolchains/trusted-toolchain-creator.armhf.precise.sh` (it will also install our QEMU package to run the ARM binaries).
There's no automatic script yet to install packages for Ubuntu 14.04, but you can look at the package list in the existing script and manually install the corresponding similar packages; I have done this on a 14.04 system but nobody has gotten around to writing a new script yet.

Note that if you don't care about testing for ARM, just switching to toolchain_build_pnacl.py will be sufficient for you because unlike build.sh it does not attempt to build any native ARM tools by default.